# Get Error Invalid CLI version provided. - Please update to at least v2.0.0 when running firebase deploy

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I am running the command firebase deploy and I see the following error:

> Invalid CLI version provided. - Please update to at least v2.0.0 by
>   running npm update -g firebase-tools

Running the command firebase -v I see I have the following version info:

`Firebase Command Line Tools
Version 1.2.0
https://www.firebase.com`

Now, running the command npm update -g firebase-tools does nada from what I can tell.

I have tried to remove and reinstall firebase-tools via the following commands:

```
npm remove -g firebase-tools
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

When I run firebase -v I continue to see version 1.2.0 and my firebase deploy continues to not work.  How do I upgrade firebase-tools to version 2?

For background info the Node version on the server is v4.3.1 and the OS is Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: `npm update -g firebase-tools`? See https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/command-line-tool.html. If that doesn't work, it seems like you may have installed node/npm as root. In that case, try `sudo npm update -g firebase-tools`.

Comment: You can also use `which firebase` to see where the firebase tool is installed and that might help you track down where the problem updating lies.

Comment: I have the same issue, updating or removing/adding package didn't do anything. I had previously installed `firebase-cli` removing it seems to fix it

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue.

I've previously installed `firebase-cli` globally (**CLI**, not **tools**), so to fix it:

```
npm remove -g firebase-cli
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: Is `firebase-cli` an unofficial package is it malicious? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57544422/is-firebase-cli-stealing-my-login-credentials

Comment: for the moment it is just a deprecated one, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-cli